# Noncommutative analogs of classical Banach geometric properties

Tags: reference-request, big-list, banach-spaces, operator-ideals

The scale of Schatten-von Neumann classes is noncommutatitve analog of classical $\ell_p$-spaces. A lot of researchers devoted their lives to study Banach geometric structure of these spaces. Different geometric properties where invented along the way. Just to name a few

- The cotype and type of Banach space
- The Radon-Nykodym property
- The approximation property
- The Dunford-Pettis property
- The property of being an $\mathscr{L}_p$-space.

I would like to know if there exists any survey on noncommutative analogs of these properties. Of course I'm interested in those properties that posessed by Schatten-von Neumann classes. I doubt that such survey exists, so references to specific properties are welcomed too.

Comment: You can start with Pisier, Gilles; Xu, Quanhua Non-commutative Lp-spaces. Handbook of the geometry of Banach spaces, Vol. 2, 1459–1517, North-Holland, Amsterdam, 2003.

Comment: @BillJohnson, thank you! This paper mostly deals with the case $1<p<\infty$. As for the edge cases, do you know a non-commutative analog of Dunford-Pettis property, a kind of property shared by bounded and nuclear operators?

Comment: No, I have not seen anything about a non commutative Dunford Pettis property.

Comment: I don't know if this is relevant to your explicit questions, but there is a long series of articles by P.G. Dodds  with various collaborators on non commutative analogues of classical function spaces.  These might be of interest and are easily traceable on mathscinet.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed the $\mathscr{L}_p$-spaces have been generalised to the non-commutative setting

> M. Junge, N.J Nielsen, Z.-J. Ruan, Q. Xu, [$\mathscr{COL}_p$-spaces—the local structure of non-commutative $L_p$-spaces](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0001870803002780), Advances in Mathematics **187**, (2004), 257–319.

There is also *operator approximation property* (try to google that name); this notion originates from the classical paper by Haagerup:

> U. Haagerup, An example of a nonnuclear C*-algebra, which has the metric approximation
>   property, *Invent. Math*. **50** (1978/79), no. 3, 279–293.